# Combobox selection loading previous selection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, variables, combobox, mfc

I have a combobox containing "1,2,3,4,5". When I make a selection in my combobox, the previous selection is loaded. For example, if the value in the combobox is "1" and I select "2", "1" is loaded into my variable `nApplication` and "2" will be displayed on my combobox. If i want to load "2", I need to change the selection one more time. Example change from "2" to "3". How do I make it load the number I select? My code looks like this.

```
void CAppDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_Application, nApplication);
.
.

void CAppDlg::OnCbnSelchangeapplication()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    int j = nApplication-1;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LABEL; i++){
        bool bShow = i < arrLabel[j];
        ((CButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_Label1+i))->ShowWindow(bShow);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the `CBN_SELCHANGE` message (mapped to the `OnCbnSelchangeapplication()` handler) is processed before the content of the combo-box is updated. `UpdateData(TRUE)` is typically called in the `OnOK()` handler, when user input has been completed. A workaround could be change the code in `OnCbnSelchangeapplication()` to post a custom message instead, and move the code you currently have there to the handler of this message. This way `UpdateData(TRUE)` would be called technically "after" the `CBN_SELCHANGE` message is processed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what do you mean by "post a custom message"?

Comment: For example, `PostMessage(WM_APP+100);` (params are by default zero). You also need to add a mapping macro in your message-map: `ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP+100, OnComboBoxChanged )`, and of course add the `OnComboBoxChanged ()` handler and move the code currently in `OnCbnSelchangeapplication()` in there.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Note that 1 is at index 0, 2 is at index 1, and so on, but you probably knew that already.

Comment: Why are you doing `nApplication-1`? `nApplication` is the active index. The selection change handler is called when the user has changed the value.

Comment: I also don't really understand what your issue is here.

Comment: The `j=nApplication-1` is because i want to call the variable `arrLabel[j]`. App 1 is linked to `arrLabel[0]`, App 2 to `arrLabel[1]` and so on.

Comment: Instead of loading the value the user clicks on, it loads the the previous value that was displayed on the combobox. eg. If the combobox is showing "1" and you change it to "5", it will load "1".

Comment: Where do I put `PostMessage(WM_APP+100);`? I don't quite understand that first part.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment, in `OnCbnSelchangeapplication()` - and move the code already there to the function mapped to the `(WM+100)` message.

Comment: I have done that. But it tells me "invalid type conversion" for `ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP+100, OnComboBoxChanged )`.

Comment: Please add the C++ tag to your question, for proper syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comments, I suspect that the contents of the combo-box are updated after the `CBN_SELCHANGE` message is processed, and that's what causing you problems. Therefore a workaround could be post a custom (application-defined) message, to be processed later.

The type of the function must be `afx_msg LRESULT (CWnd::*)(WPARAM, LPARAM)` (check the documentation).

So, in your class declaration, add:

```
public:
afx_msg LRESULT OnComboSelChanged(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

In your message-map:

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP+100, OnComboSelChanged)
```

And finally the implementation:

```
void CAppDlg::OnCbnSelchangeapplication()
{
    // Place a message in the message queue
    PostMessage(WM_APP+100);
}

LRESULT CAppDlg::OnComboSelChanged(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    int j = nApplication-1;

    // I have simplified your code a little
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LABEL; i++)
        GetDlgItem(IDC_Label1+i)->ShowWindow(i < arrLabel[j]);

    return 0L;
}
```

---

However, all this, ie calling `UpdateData(TRUE);`, get the string there, convert it to `int` and take actions depending on its value, may just be an overkill, esp if the combo-box contains just a contiguous number-range (1..5 in your case). `UpdateData(TRUE);` transfers the values in ALL your controls to variables, and this may just not be needed. It seems to be a mechanism controlling the appearance of other controls, it's not really "data-entry" (I guess the combod-box is a non-editable drop-down list). So, you could just not use `DDX/DDV` at all, instead check the selected item yourself. It's a zero-based index. Here is the code:

```
void CAppDlg::OnCbnSelchangeapplication()
{
    // Get selected item
    int j = ((CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(DC_Application))->GetCurSel();
    if (j == CB_ERR) return;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_LABEL; i++)
        GetDlgItem(IDC_Label1+i)->ShowWindow(i < arrLabel[j]);
}
```

Please note that the code fragments above have not been tested, it's just what I would do.